# PHP check curl result is XML or HTML

Tags: php

I'm running a curl request with PHP and the results are loaded in a $result variable. I can echo this $result variable. I want to load the $result into simplexml_load_string. However, if I do this and if there is a problem with the website request then i will potentially end up with a html page that is converted to XML using the simplexml_load_string

So what I want to do is only put the $result into the simplexml_load_string if the $result is actually XML. If it's XML the $result usually starts with <?xml otherwise it starts with <!DOCTYPE or <html

Any ideas how I can do this? I tried using the following to check the first 5 characters but that returns errors.

```
substr($result, 0, 5)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be substr($result, 0, 4) ? [0]<[1]?[2]x[3]m[4]l

Comment: oops yeh but it still doesn't work. Doesn't seem like it likes me loading $result into substr, i think maybe it's too large

Comment: can you post all the curl code?  There are tons of things you can do to check if request is successful (check response code) and to check the response content type .... Post all the curl code !

Comment: Look here - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php There is a good example with CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE - so you know http response code 200OK, 500Internal Server Error etc. etc. Also you have CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE - https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE.html

Comment: Just don't try to figure out what the server response is by using PHP substr($result....), because all this info you may need is included in the response from the server :)